# Number of primes of a certain form

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

Let $p_n$ be the nth prime. Are there an infinite number of primes of the form 
$2p_n+1$? Is something known about questions like this?

Comment: Such $p_n$ are [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime). Not known whether there are infinitely many.

Comment: @DanielFischer. OK! Testing $ap_n+b$ for large $a,b$ and $n$ suggests that there are infinitely many as well.

Comment: If a and b are coprime.

Comment: There are more of these conjectures, all of them are extremely hard. A similar question is, are there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p!-1$ or $p!+1$ are prime? There seems to be little progress on these type of questions. The most notable recent theorem on primes numbers states that there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions of primes (Green-Tao theorem). Obviously that doesn't solve these questions, but it is remarkable.

Comment: Although proofs are hard to come by, one can use heuristics to derive an estimate for the number of primes of the form $2p+1$ up to a some $x$.  In most cases the reality matches very closely to the conjectured formula for $x$ as high as we can compute, suggesting that the formula remains accurate for all $x$ (if so, then there are infinitely many such primes).  This can be considered much stronger empirical evidence than just testing specific primes randomly, but it still doesn't constitute a proof.

Comment: @Lehs What about when $a$ and $b$ are coprime, and odd?